# Use LaTeX3 variables within TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3, expl3

I’m new to LaTeX3 and don’t understand why the following doesn’t work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N { \g_tobi_color_tl }
\tl_set:Nn { \g_tobi_color_tl } { red }

\tl_new:N { \g_tobi_radius_tl }
\tl_set:Nn { \g_tobi_radius_tl } { 1em }

\NewDocumentCommand { \usevar } { m }
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_tobi_#1_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Color: \usevar{color}

Radius: \usevar{radius}

\tikz \fill [\usevar{color}] circle [radius=\usevar{radius}] ;
\end{document}
```

Is it a conflict between L3 and TikZ? And is it possible to fix this?

The “classical“ way works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\def\var@color{red}
\def\var@radius{1em}

\newcommand{\usevar}[1]{%
 \csuse{var@#1}%
}

\begin{document}
Color: \usevar{color}

Radius: \usevar{radius}

\tikz \fill [\usevar{color}] circle [radius=\usevar{radius}] ;
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not that you ask for it but `\makeatletter
\def\var@color{red}
\def\var@radius{1em}
\def\usevar#1{\csname var@#1\endcsname }
\makeatother` looks a little easier. So you don't need to expand it additionally once more.

Comment: @percusse: Isn’t that the same as my “classical” version, except that I use `etoolbox`’ `\csdef`, which is a little shorter?!

Comment: Yes indeed but you skip a package :P

Comment: That’s an argument … :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two hints:

1. You need an expandable version of `\usevar`. This can be achieved by `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`
2. The specifier `N` requires an unbraced token.

Here the example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \g_tobi_color_tl 
\tl_set:Nn  \g_tobi_color_tl  { red }

\tl_new:N \g_tobi_radius_tl 
\tl_set:Nn \g_tobi_radius_tl  { 1em }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand { \usevar } { m }
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_tobi_#1_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Color: \usevar{color}

Radius: \usevar{radius}

\tikz \fill [\usevar{color}] circle [radius=\usevar{radius}] ;
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you! But why does it work with braced arguments even there is the upper case `N`. I didn’t see any warning …

Comment: @Tobi, because there is no reasonably efficient way for LaTeX3 to enforce that there be no braces (given the tools TeX provides).  Most of the time, `N` versus `n` is just a convention which helps know which arguments should be single tokens versus multiple (braced) tokens.  But every here and there, braces are mandatory, or forbidden (e.g., with `\cs_set_eq:NN` the second `N` argument mustn't be braced), so you're safer sticking with conventions.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: That makes sense, thanks for your explanation!